# JW Player seek and pause from click

Tags: javascript, onclick, jwplayer, seek

I need to create a video player using jwplayer that can play thru specific areas of a video. Im doing this to reduce the amount of videos we need to load on page load and hopefully simplify ongoing updates if the timing needs adjustment later.  I would just modify the data attributes.

I do not want request a page refresh, or a different video.

GOAL: *The desired behavior would be, hit button 1, play 0-10 seconds and pause. Hit button 2, play 11-20 seconds and pause. hit the first button and repeat the behavior if desired.*

the buttons would exist like this:

I made some code updates but the functionality isn't fully working.  This only now works after hitting the button twice... If hit 0-15, then hit 15-25, it starts to play then just stops. I believe that the stop is being caused by the stop im calling within the condition?

```
 <section>
    <div class="seeker" data-start="0" data-end="15">Go there and pause</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="seeker" data-start="16" data-end="20">Go there and pause</div>
</section>

 jwplayer("player").setup({
    file: "http://sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4",
 });
$(function(){
    $("section").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".seeker").bind('click',function(){
            var start = $(this).data('start'),
                end   = $(this).data('end');

            jwplayer().play();

            jwplayer().seek(start).onTime(function(event) {
                if(event.position>end) {
                 jwplayer().stop();
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

This code works on load so the functionality is def working but I just need to attach to the click and use the 'start','end' vars.

```
        jwplayer().onReady(function(){ 
             jwplayer().seek(0).onTime(function(event) {
                 if(event.position>15) {
                     jwplayer().stop();
                 }
             });
        });
```

Work in progress is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/n2rpq1t4/21/

Comment: Do you have an example of where you are trying to run this? A sample test page link?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer - edited my question. thx

Comment: It seems as though the problem lies in the condition: if(event.position > end ) { jwplayer().stop(); } ... the event.position does not get reset after each click.  Is there a way to to this?

Comment: jwplayer().seek(0).onTime(function(event) { Should not be used here. It should be just jwplayer().onTime(function(event) {

Comment: Player not showing up on the fiddle, I get the following - A username and password are being requested by http://staging.ffy.thisisdk.com. The site says: "Restricted"

Comment: aw sorry about that. http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/n2rpq1t4/21/

Comment: I would update the player version. 6.1 is pretty old. 6.12 is the latest version of JW6. http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/jwplayer.js Another thing, it looks like you are making the player pause if the time is higher than the start param, which is why it pauses when seek. Try this updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/r2pkhcre/2/

Comment: Ive updated my question withe overall goal. Sorry, i did not make it to clear.  latest fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/n2rpq1t4/24/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86835/discussion-between-arkjoseph-and-ethan-jwplayer).

Comment: I guess I do not fully understand the use case here. Are you trying to make it seek, then pause after the seek event happens?

Comment: Yes. That is the goal

Comment: What about something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/a8dao9d4/2/